# how to guarantee the order of response in a service-oriented mmo server cluster

Tags: networking, server

i'm working on a mmo server these days. it's a service-oriented architecture, every service is one process which processes a specific type of request, and i have inventory service, battle service, etc.
  when received a request from client, the request will be dispatched to some corresponding service, based on the request type. 
  let's assume we received two requests from one client in the cluster-side request message queue, first request1 and then request2, then the two requests will be dispatched to service1 and service2. so request2 may be handled first and the client will receive response2 first and then response1, which will not be what the client expect.
  so i'm wondering how to guarantee that response will go back in the same order request come?

Comment: Add an client request Id to the requests. And then do the response ordering in the network layer of the client. This way the servers don't need to do synchronization

Comment: but what if the result of request1 will affect the result of request2?

Comment: Surely you jest, how can your server answer question two first if it depends on result one. If you mean it request one alters the server state that request two depends on. Now you talking standard DB logic. Ether have queries processed in order. Or use locks on critical tables.

Answer (score 1):

A [slideshow (note: written in Korean language)](http://www.slideshare.net/ssusere2065c/ndc-public) say that [Vindictus](http://vindictus.nexon.net/) is a kind of service-oriented architecture MMO server.

Service-oriented architecture can handle massive concurrent players with its scale-out ability, but it is a kind of inter-process asynchronous programming. Like other asynchronous programming, service-oriented architecture must be taken into care or you will suffer from many [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

In Vindictus server case, the server is split into two kinds: front-end and back-end. front-end server is horizontally sharded so every front-end server do the same role. Front-end servers are directly connected to game clients. Meanwhile, back-end servers do the service role and they do different roles. Game clients never connect directly to back-end servers.

Every request from clients is always arrived front-end servers, so their processing is always ordered. Each request is dispatched to a back-end server then it will response to the same front-end server. [#2] If the request needs more processing by another back-end server, then it is dispatched to it and then returns. [#1]

[image: Sequence diagram of processing a request through several servers]

Such a service-oriented architecture is a good way for scale-out servers, but this method makes too long latency to use it for [fast-action gameplay of Vindictus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cqkXIJPTJo). So it uses [P2P networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) in gameplay itself.